# How to use the "Extensible choice parameter" in a jenkins freestyle job located on the slave to show files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have a freestyle job and a parameterized build.
I want to populate an ***Extensible Choice*** with all xml file names inside my workspace.
Both the job and the workspace are running on the slave.

[image: Exentsible Choice]

The textbox ***Base Directory*** says that every relative path has *JENKINS_HOME* as root, and that is the Jenkins location on the master. Something like C:/ has the same outcome.

I have the same problem with the ***Active Choice Parameter***.
I don't know how to get access to my workspace, with the groovy script for my parameter.
I've tried the following:

```
def list = []

def dir = new File("C:/<path>")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  list << file
}
```

It results in a FileNotFoundException. When I try to input a path to the master, it works fine.
I labeled the slave and the job correctly (The job will only be executed on the slave).

Does anyone has a solution?

Comment: If I understand correctly, by active choice parameter you mean dropdown parameter right ? Active choice parameter script is always running on master, so the file you look for has to be in jenkins master. Your requirement might be achievable if you define logic in your active choice script for master to fetch list of file of one specific executor.

Every script that ran outside jenkins job execution is always ran on master

Comment: Okay thank you, I've done research for a workaround and have found this solution: ```Hudson.instance.items[1].getAllJobs()```. Here I can determine the job and would call the method ```getSomeWorkspace().list()``` to list the files of the workspace.